# Bing Food & Drink app always crashes

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, modern-ui, windows-store-app

My Food & Drink app that came pre-installed on my Windows 8.1 PC keeps crashing to the start screen immediately after opening. Other Bing-based apps work fine. I've taken several steps to try to fix this, but to no avail. I know there're about three duplicates of this, but none of the answers worked.

Here are the steps I did:

- I tried reinstalling the app, doesn't work
- I tried the app troubleshooter, doesn't work
- I tried to reset the Store, and it doesn't work either
- I tried giving full permission to ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES to C:\User, doesn't work
- I tried fully removing the app using PowerShell, but the issue still persists
- I used sfc /scannow, doesn't work.

and just for your information:

- My screen resolution is above the one required.
- My Display driver is up to date.
- I don't use proxy.
- Although the app is not working, the live tile of the app is working.
- All other apps work fine.

I went to see the Event Viewer and found these logs:

```
Activation of app Microsoft.BingFoodAndDrink_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexFoodAndDrink failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

and this from the Windows Error Reporting

```
    Fault bucket 98797442235, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.BingFoodAndDrink_3.0.2.229_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
P2: praid:AppexFoodAndDrink
P3: 6.3.9600.16431
P4: 525e5d4e
P5: KERNELBASE.dll
P6: 6.3.9600.16496
P7: 52b3f283
P8: 00000004
P9: 0000000000005a88
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\Prakrit\AppData\Local\Temp\WER5E02.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Prakrit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.BingFo_81bdfb3b1e47e3789768dc66f83b1d2d4211057_d1dbbf47_00f46dd1

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 0a55633e-a1d7-11e3-bed7-2c41385d9572
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: e353c7d152e971712c838cd55ea8ea34
```

and the Application Error

```
Faulting application name: wwahost.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16431, time stamp: 0x525e5d4e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16496, time stamp: 0x52b3f283
Exception code: 0x00000004
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005a88
Faulting process id: 0x29e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf35e3cca2fbad
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\wwahost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 0a55633e-a1d7-11e3-bed7-2c41385d9572
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.BingFoodAndDrink_3.0.2.229_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: AppexFoodAndDrink
```

How can I fix this without having to refresh/reset the machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try all steps from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx

Comment: A couple of questions: Are you logging on using a local account or a Windows Id? Have you tried creating another test account on the computer and using that?

Comment: I'm logged on using Microsoft Account. Tried logging in again with a local account, but the same problem occurs.